# In Ruby, what - technically - does array.reject or array.select without a block do?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerator

So far as I can tell, `array.reject` and `array.select` do nothing:

```
[nil, false, true].reject  # Should have been reject.to_a for this example.
 => [nil, false, true] 
[nil, false, true].select  # Should have been select.to_a for this example.
 => [nil, false, true]
```

For the code I was trying to write, `compact` was what I needed, but I'm very curious why `reject` and `select` without a block do nothing - I was expecting a default block of `{ |e| e }` so `reject` would be `compact` and 'select' would be some weird anti-compact.

What is the default block doing?

---

Edit: Sorry, I missed off the '.to_a' on the ends of the expressions above, which I was hoping would trigger some sort of lazy evaluation and make the reject/select enumeration do something useful. I normally cut&paste my examples to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: it returns [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html)

Comment: In my irb, `[nil, false, true].reject => #<Enumerator: [nil, false, true]:reject>`, which pretty much answers the question.

Comment: Select without a block returns an enumerator, just like the docs say; I'm not sure why you'd expect it to be anything other than the original array. I don't see why `reject` with no rejection criteria would be anything other than the original array as well--why would it be a `compact` if there's no reason given to reject an element?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I don't think there has ever been a version of Ruby where those return `self` or `self.dup` when passed no block. It was an error in 1.8.6- and returns an enumerator in 1.8.7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block is optional for many Ruby methods. When no block is given an enumerator is usually returned. There are at least a couple of reasons you might want an enumerator.

**#1 Use the enumerator with the methods in the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html).**

Here's an example. Suppose you wish to alternate the case of letters in a string. One conventional way is:

```
"oh happy day".each_char.with_index.map { |c,i| i.odd? ? c.upcase : c.downcase }.join
  #=> "oH HaPpY DaY"
```

but you could instead write:

```
enum = [:odd, :even].cycle
"oh happy day".each_char.map { |c| enum.next==:odd ? c.upcase : c.downcase }.join
```

or perhaps

```
enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
"oh happy day".each_char.map { |c| c.send(enum.next) }.join
```

See the docs for [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

**#2 Use enumerators to chain methods**

In my first example above, I wrote:

```
"oh happy day".each_char.with_index.map...
```

If you examine the docs for [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) you will see that both methods can be used with or without a block. Here they are both used without a block. That enables the three methods to be *chained*.

Study the return values in the following.

```
enum0 = "oh happy day".each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "oh happy day":each_char> 
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "oh happy day":each_char>:with_index> 
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #     "oh happy day":each_char>:with_index>:map>
```

You might want to think of `enum1` and `enum2` as "compound" enumerators.

You show the return value of:

```
[nil, false, true].reject
```

to be:

```
#=> [nil, false, true]
```

but that is not correct. The return value is:

```
#<Enumerator: [nil, false, true]:reject>
```

If we write:

```
enum = [nil, false, true].reject
```

then:

```
enum.each { |e| e }
  #=> [nil, false]
```

(which, since Ruby v2.3, we could write `enum.reject(&:itself)`). This uses the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), causing `enum` to invoke [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) because `reject`'s receiver is an instance of the class `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer, particularly the subtle point about the reject enumeration being operated on by a block distinct from its creation point. I use the chaining idiom fairly frequently, but hadn't considered what types were being operated on 'between the dots'.  (I find myself rankling at writing `.each { |e| e }` but I hate monkey-patching, so I'll just have to yearn for something like an `.it` method defined to be that in some future version of Ruby. :)

Comment: @android.weasel Why would you write `.each { |e| e }`?

Answer (score 2):

makes an `Enumerator` of it:

```
en = [1,2,3].reject
# => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:reject>
en.each{|n| n == 1}
# => [2, 3]
```

Comment: You're right. I normally copy-paste my examples, but didn't that time. What was confusing me was that trying to coerce that enumeration into doing something useful, by using .to_a, just gave all the values back, with no rejection happening anywhere. @CarySwoveland's response shows that it needs to be iterated with `each{|e|e}` to make it do something useful - which was what I ended up doing, but without understanding why what (still) seems like obvious default behaviour wasn't obtaining.